# android layout issue - separating the screen into two layouts (inside a tab)

Tags: android, list, layout, tabs

I have tabhost and in 1 tab I want to do the following:
1. At the top - a search edittext.
2. Below it some textbox. When user press the search button - I need this textbox to be changed into a list, on the rest of the screen (below the search).

Actually I need to separate the screen into 2 part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way, but something like this is fairly basic and should work.  If you use a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) just specify the image as the id/empty and the listview as the id/list.  Then when your list is empty, users see the `ImageView`.  When you populate it, it'll switch automatically.

```
<LinearLayout ...
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout ...>

    <EditText .../>

    <ImageButton .../>

  </LinearLayout>

  <ImageView ...
     android:id="@android:id/empty"/>

  <ListView ...
     android:id="@android:id/list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you can't use `ListActivity`, just do it yourself (e.g. in the click listener for the button):

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.YOUR-IMAGEVIEW);
image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

ListView list = findViewById(R.id.YOUR-LISTVIEW);
list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And be sure to set `android:visibility="gone"` on your list in the XML to make it be initially hidden.

Comment: Actually what I need is the linearlayout, edit text, image.... When user does the search - need to remove the image and instead put a list

Answer (score 0):

Add a common layout in tab host as parent layout and add or remove the view as u like.